# Why I am getting wrong matrix norm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, floating-point, numerical-methods

I have small, well conditioned hermitian matrix L with eigenvalues in [0,2]. I'm getting weird results while trying to compute norm of inverse of L:

```
>> norm(inv(L))

ans =

    2.0788

>> min(eig(L))

ans =

    0.5000
```

Which is strange because second norm of inverse ought to be equal inverse of minimal eigenvalue of matrix.

I know about errors introduced by machine arithmetic, but in this small, hermitian and well-conditioned  example I expected it to be negligible.

Here is the matrix https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh1wegrnn53wb6w/matrix.mat

I'm using matlab 8.2.0.701 (R2013b) on Linux mint 16 (Petra).

Comment: 729x729 is a "small" matrix?

Comment: @Daniel, yes it is, and moreover this one is a sparse matrix.

Comment: You say `well conditioned hermitian matrix L with eigenvalues in [0,1]`, but this is not what I get: `e=eig(L); max(e) -->   1.3789,  min(e)-->  0.5000`

Comment: @Nasser, sorry for typo, it ought to be [0, 2].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a numerical issue, as you've pointed out the matrix is well-conditioned.

> second norm of inverse ought to be equal inverse of minimal eigenvalue of matrix

This is only true if the matrix is hermitian with positive eigenvalues (ie positive definite). From wikipedia: The spectral norm of a matrix A is the largest singular value of A i.e. the square root of the largest eigenvalue of the positive-semidefinite matrix A*A

So here you would calculate the norm of the inverse as:

```
[v,d] = eig(L'*L);
1.0/sqrt(min(diag(d))) = 2.0788539
norm(inv(L)) = 2.0788539
```

As we expect.

Comment: Which then shows that the matrix can not really be hermitean, i.e., symmetric if it has real entries. Or not positive definite. Because for symmetric positive definite (spd) matrices the original reasoning would be correct, then the eigenvalues are also the singular values.

Comment: @LutzL, yes, matrix is not really hermitean, this was the case. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Thanks LutzL, I've made a small edit to incorporate your comment.